# Laptop screen doesn't work after standby - hit or miss

Tags: screen, acer

I have an Acer Aspire 5750 and if i let my computer sit for 4hrs - 48 hrs, when i open up the laptop lid, my screen is black. The computer is still on, but it won't wake up.

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock the computer.

Any help will be appreciated

edit*

this computer has the 2nd gen intel core i5 sandybridge integrated graphics. I had the same problem on 12.04 and 12.10.

Comment: Have you tried [aceracpi](https://code.google.com/p/aceracpi/).  Have you tried `apt-get install acpi acpid`?

Comment: Also an issue on my Lenovo IdeaPad Z570, although I'm pretty sure it is a bug and so I don't think this is the best place to put it. The workaround I found is to hit CTRL-ALT-F2 to bring up a terminal, login there, then type


'sudo pkill -kill -u <username>'.

This should bring you back to the login screen. You will be logged out and lose work, however.

Comment: I have a Toshiba s1000-z2 that has the same sort of problem. However, I know that my problem lies with the sensor that detects that the lid is shut. In my case this is a small switch that is pushed down when the lid is closed. When I hold a medium brightness slightly tilted upwards to the screen I can still see it. It seems that only the backlight is turned off, and not the LCD itself. Try holding a flashlight. Wiggle the mouse first though. Can you see anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change brightness (press the brightness up button)?

I can't find the links right now to post here, but there are reports that in some laptops when opening the screen lid again the brightness is minimum, in some cases it's like the screen is black. Pressing the brightness up solves in those cases.

Also there are scripts to automatically turn brightness up when keyboard shortcuts are not available or do not work.

Answer (score 0):

@earthmeLon suggested to execute

```
sudo apt-get install acpi acpid
```

in a terminal. I had a similar problem, and that solved it. I would like to hear the result of this attempt, since you haven't posted that yet.

EDIT: Or actually `sudo apt-get install acpi`solved it for me, acpid was already installed.

Answer (score -2):

I have had a similar issue it was fixed by installing my GPU drivers from the manufacturer. But I went to my laptop manufacturer and found a complete linux driver pack with rpm and autoconf downloads.

Here is the [link](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers) to the drivers page for your laptop but they have only Windows drivers. I also could not find third party linux drivers for your laptop. You probably have mesa nut it is a gnu compatible version of openGL I would recommend updating/installing other packages for mesa.

Sorry I could not be of further assistance.

okay **lucio** this is an unconventional fix but you could change this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

in the file `/etc/default/grub`, then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

this adds brightness adjustment but still no fix for the screen to turn on. it seems this is a very common issue with acer aspire series.

Comment: If your link have only links to Windows drivers, than this "answer" should be removed. Beside the link, this doesn't seems to be helpful.